# How can I render a custom JSON error response "Couldn't find Plan with id" in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I would like to render a custom error that shows when the user cannot find the class 'Plan' by id. The problem is that it's not reaching the `if` statement.

**NB**. I am using Insomnia to test it.

```
class Api::V1::PlansController < Api::V1::BaseController
  before_action :authorize_request

  def show
    @plan = Plan.find(params[:id])
    if @plan.errors.any?
      render json 'wrong'
    else
      @accounts = @plan.accounts
      render json: @plan, status: :created
    end
  end

end
```

[image]

Comment: use `find_by_id`, it will return `nil` instead of raising an error. You might want to change that conditional to something like `if @plan.nil?`

Comment: wow, so fast haha yeah, it worked. many thanks

Comment: Hi, I am adding as a answer. Please mark and vote up. May be it will help someone.

Answer (score 2):

[`ActiveRecord::FinderMethods#find`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) will raise an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception when if one the ids cannot be found. And when an exception is raised it halts execution.

You can handle the exception by using [`rescue_from`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html#method-i-rescue_from):

```
# Do not use the scope resolution operator when declaring classes and modules
# @see https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#namespace-definition
module Api
  module V1
    class PlansController < BaseController
      before_action :authorize_request
      rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :not_found

      def show
        @plan = Plan.find(params[:id])
        render json: @plan
      end

      private

      def not_found
        render json: { error: 'not found' }, status: :not_found       
      end      
    end
  end
end
```

The recommendation to use [`find_by`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by) might sound like a good idea initially until you realize that the exception is really useful as it halts execution of the action and prevents nil errors.

```
module Api
  module V1
    class PlansController < BaseController
      # ... 
      before_action :set_plan

      def update
        # this would create a nil error if we had used 'find_by'
        if @plan.update(plan_params)
          # ...
        else
          # ...
        end
      end

      private
      def set_plan
        @plan = Plan.find(params[:id])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Using `rescue_from` is also a really powerful pattern as it lets you move error handling up in the inheritance chain instead of repeating yourself:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class BaseController < ::ActionController::Api
      rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :not_found

      private
    
      def not_found
         render json: { error: 'not found' }, status: :not_found       
      end   
    end
  end
end
```

But most likely you don't even need this at all in the first place. Rails rescues `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` on the framework level by sending a `404 - Not Found` response. Clients should not need any more context then the status code in this case and returning completely unessicary JSON error message responses is an anti-pattern.